# Ionic 3 - Issue converting JSON data to Object then displaying in list

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic-framework

I am creating a travel application using Ionic 3, Angular and Cordova, with the intention of getting train information from transportAPI.com to display in a list.

The HTML for the list page:

```
    <ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor = "let train of trainList">
      {{train.name}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

The code for my home page, home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TravelServiceProvider} from '../../providers/travel-service/travel-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  trainList = [];

  constructor(private travelService : TravelServiceProvider) {
    this.getTravel();
  }

  getTravel(){
    this.travelService.getTravel().subscribe(data => this.trainList = data);
  }
}
```

My provider class is as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class TravelServiceProvider {

  private url : string = "http://transportapi.com/v3/uk/places.json?query=&type=train_station&app_id=91676f07&app_key=e10dc441385db6f855e3e5ad29bcd6c8";

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello TravelServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  getTravel(){
    return this.http.get(this.url)
    .do(this.logResponse)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.catchError)
  }

  private logResponse(res : Response){
    console.log(res);
  }

  private extractData(res : Response){
    return res.json();
  }

  private catchError(error : Response | any){
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || "Server Error" );
  }
}
```

I am expecting to see the train names in the JSON to be printed in list form, by the *ngFor expression in the HTML, but instead nothing is displayed in place of the {{train.name}}, and I get the error "Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you getting an array in your trainList ?

Comment: yes, but with the response header, not body.

Comment: try to use JSON.parse to get body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says you need to provide an array for ngFor , I think you need to access the member property of the response object which is an array, change it as

```
this.travelService.getTravel().subscribe((data:any) => this.trainList = data.member);
```

Comment: what does the :any in data mean?

Comment: it means, type of the response is any, so that you can access the members of it using dot operator